# Why does the procedure only work in one sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, module

I wrote a procedure that filters a table ("Tabela1") into sheet1 (technical name: arkusz1) and copies the uniques to sheet 2 (technical name: wsPOMOC).
Then, through a "for each" loop, the combined text is returned to cell B3 (arkusz1).

If the procedure is in sheet 2 (wsPOMOC), it works.
However, if it is in the module, an error appears when "set range..."
"Run-time error '1004:
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

Please help me and tell me what could be the reason that the procedure only works if it is in the help sheet wsPOMOC?

```
Sub FilrtrowanieUnikatowychDanych()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wyraz As Range
Dim Ciagpolaczony As String
Dim ilewierszy As Integer
Dim zakres As Range

wsPOMOC.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Clear

Arkusz1.Range("Tabela1").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Arkusz1.Range("Tabela1[Kolumna1]"), CopyToRange:= _
wsPOMOC.Range("A3"), Unique:=True

ilewierszy = wsPOMOC.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Set zakres = wsPOMOC.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(ilewierszy + 2, 1))

Arkusz1.Range("B3").Clear

For Each wyraz In zakres
    Ciagpolaczony = Ciagpolaczony & wyraz & ",!"
Next wyraz

Arkusz1.Range("B3").Value = "!" & Trim(Ciagpolaczony)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

The procedure only works if there is a hard range:
Set zakres = wsPOMOC.Range("A3:A10").

However, I need dynamic range

Answer (score 0):

```
Set zakres = wsPOMOC.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(ilewierszy + 2, 1))
-->
Set zakres = wsPOMOC.Range(wsPOMOC.Cells(3, 1), wsPOMOC.Cells(ilewierszy + 2, 1))
```

`Cells` without the object reference is applied to the ActiveSheet. The error occurs when wsPOMOC in not the ActiveSheet.